# Firebase Hosting Setup Complete

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

Could please someone help me to fix this issue? I'm trying to update my project, but I'm having problems with firebase deploy. Or rather the deploy goes fine, but I can't see my project on the browser I always receive this message:

```
Firebase Hosting Setup Complete
You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION
```

The messages that I receive after running firebase deploy

```
i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: found 49 files in dist/webpage
✔  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: file upload complete
i  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: version finalized
i  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[webpage-1ffe0]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!
```

My domains on Firebase page

```
webpage-1ffe0.web.app
default

webpage-1ffe0.firebaseapp.com
default

www.webpage.com
redirect
```

And my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/webpage",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the content of your `dist/webpage` directory?

Comment: Hi @RenaudTarnec the content of my dist/webpage is the same of my src folder. 
I generated the dist/webpge content by ng build --prod

Comment: Ok, but what do you have in this folder? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I updated the image above in the issue description, I hope it could help you

Comment: You config should work since you have an `index.html` file under the `dist/webpage` directory. What happens if you delete the `public` directory and re-deploy? One question: Where is your `firebase.json` file exactly located? It should be at the same level than the `dist` directory

Comment: My firebase.json is the same level as my dist folder, by the way now everything works well. I just had to wait for a bit. Anyway @RenaudTarnec do you know how I can clear the firebase cache? Or How can I delete the css / js file genereted by each deploy? Thanks in advance